# Astyle not working

Tags: astyle

I downloaded Astyle from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/files/

When I execute Astyle.exe in \bin a command prompt opens which looks like this: 
[image]

I can't execute any commands. Astlye.exe seems to be stuck. I've read the documentation for Quick Start and simple commands multiple times, but could not find my error, so I think, I`m overlooking something obvious.

I realize, there have been similare questions, but none of them could solve my problem.

EDIT: I also rebuild the Astyle.exe. Same problem as before.

Answer (score 1):

The default for most linux-based tools is to read from the standard input if no file is specified (so that one can "pipe" into it).

What you are seeing is simply `astyle` waiting for input. If you specify a file on the command-line or the `--help` flag, you'll see more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a console(cmd window) and go to the directory which contains the astyle program. Run the program in the console.